# want to implement SOAP API (server) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, soap, laravel-5.6

i want to write a web service that will just return some data from my database its in below format

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<AgentDetails xmlns="http://cdlmsp.prasware.com/distribution">
<UserID>xyz</UserID>
<Name>aabbcc xxyyzz</Name>
<PhoneNumber>00998890900</PhoneNumber>
<EmailAddress>aa@aa.com</EmailAddress>
</AgentDetails>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to write soap server for this i failed to find any packages for writing soap api with laravel can any one suggest some good packages or any ideas?

Comment: you mean you already tried [this](https://www.google.de/search?q=laravel+soap+server&oq=laravel+soap+server&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60j0l3.3063j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ?

Comment: yes @Dragos....

Comment: Try this https://codecr8.com/php-create-laravel-soap-server/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick: [viewflex/zoap](https://github.com/viewflex/zoap) (for Laravel and Lumen) turns any class into a WS-I compliant SOAP web service, with automatic discovery and generation of WSDL definitions. It includes a demo service already configured as an example, with a collection of Postman requests including tests.